# Different line-height and baseline on mobile and desktops

Tags: html, css, fonts, baseline

This is the third time I have faced this problem.

I don't know what is wrong.
Here are two pictures of how it looks like:

On desktops:

[image]

On mobile devices:

[image]

As you can see on mobile devices text is not aligned center vertically.

Again this problem is only visible on mobile devices.

What is the problem? What did I miss? This problem is also visible in inputs.

I am using the following code for the buttons:

```
.button
  font-family: 'Gotham Pro', sans-serif
  font-size: 14px
  color: $color-text--button
  padding: 10px 15px
  text-transform: uppercase
  background: $color-button--default
  border: 1px solid $color-transparent
```

**Please note, I use padding for setting height of buttons**

**UPDATE**

I have just tested in mobile android Firefox browser, everything works just fine the issue only with `Chrome`

Comment: I just tried that CSS of yours and have no issues on mobile. Please post a code snippet that reproduces the issue, or else we have nothing to work with.

Comment: Try reset the `line-height` to somewhere between 1 and 1.2. When not set/reset the browsers default can differ, so Chrome might give it something else by default

Answer (score 1):

There is no line-height specified in your code.

Try setting a specific line-height. In addition I suggest, that you center your text via line-height and not via padding. Set a line-height with the same height the button has.

**CSS**

```
.button {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

This works of course only for single line texts.
Also have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css)

Comment: but why does this work on desktops, and I don't want to set static height of the button, using padding is more flexible

Comment: With the given information it is hard to guess. Maybe there is an user-agent style in chrome causing the issue. Did you try setting a fixed line-height?

Comment: Using line height property with static height it works, but I cannot do this, I have buttons dynamically height according to padding

Comment: @gzbuaapzroyn As I already commented, we need a code snippet reproducing the issue to be able to give you a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify a media query SPECIFICALLY for mobile?
You may need to add

```
// you can use any other value of screen width mobiles use like 640, 768
@media (max-width:480px){
    line-height: 15px;  // The line height you want to show on mobile
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all browsers have a default. Almost always I make a habit of setting styles on the body element

```
body{
 font-size: 100%;
 line-height: 1.333%;
}
```

to take care of things like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had to work with a *fancy font* today and I noticed that it has different line-height rendering on *chrome mobile* device and *chrome desktop* mobile emulator (devtools). Which is apparently a **bug** to be reported for either dekstop either mobile chrome. Changing *line-heights* is the option to fix but cumbersome if you have many elements. After some digging I figured out this properties

```
ascent-override: 92%; /* play with values */
descent-override: 10%; /* one might not be needed */
```

Futhermore as I needed font change for mobile chrome only I tried media query and it worked.

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  @font-face{
    font-family:'FancyFont';
    src:url('fonts/FancyFont.ttf');
    font-weight:400;
    ascent-override: 92%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works like a charm:

```
  descent-override: 0%;
  ascent-override: 72%;
  line-gap-override: 3%;
```

Reference: https://codepen.io/web-dot-dev/pen/poeLebG